# SQL Query to find invoices where invoicedate is over due from a date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have two input fields
     **[start_date] - [end_date]**

Whenever you type in a date range in YYYY-MM-DD, f.e: **[2015-12-01] - [2015-12-05]**

I want to make an SQL query to find out which invoices that **is due** in that period.

There is no column in the database that stores the duedate, only the invoice_date.

**Due date is always invoice_date + 17days**

Is there anyway to extract the relevant invoices from this?

This is my current query, but it only picks invoices thats has been generated in the range.

**I want it to find those who are DUE in the above entered range**.

```
 select * from orders
        inner join 
        order_invoice on order_invoice.id_order = orders.id_order
        where (current_state = 14) and 
        orders.date_add >= "'.$start_date.'" and
        orders.date_add <= "'.$end_date.'" and
        now() >= DATE_ADD(order_invoice.date_add, INTERVAL 17 DAY)
```

Comment: mssql: `due_date = dateadd(day,17,invoice_date)`  mysql: `date_add(invoice_date, INTERVAL 17 DAYS)`

Comment: I've tried this solution but that only extends the query-span with 17 days, i want it to find the invoices that is expired (where date_add+17 is in the above entered range) @Used_By_Already

Comment: For SQL-server: use the where clause as 'dateadd(day,17,invoice_date) BETWEEN [startdate] AND [enddate]'

Comment: The tags say mySql **and** Sql Server, but the syntax says MySql, Based on that, I've removed the Sql-Server tag from your question.

Comment: use OR instead of and in the last condition of now().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your range (`[start_date]` and `[end_date]`) 17 days left (subtract from date params) and you will get range for `date_add`. No difference: to add 17 days to date_add or to subtract same value from both range bounds.

And I actually don't understand what is `now()` function doing in filter predicate. Seems it does not correspond task described. May be you have to think up something for `[end_date]` for proper current date/future handling.

Comment: so i should use this approach for correct result?

... 
ps_order_invoice.date_add >= DATE_SUB('START_DATE', INTERVAL 17 DAY)
and
ps_order_invoice.date_add <= DATE_SUB('END_DATE', INTERVAL 17 DAY) 
....